# validate in backbone is not working

Tags: backbone.js

Seems backbone validate has some issue in executing.

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults:{
        name:'Jagadeesh',
        age:28,
        child:'Bhuvan'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('error',function(model,error){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
        });
    },

    validate:function(attributes){
        if(attributes.age < 0){
            console.log('You cant be negative years old');
            return "You can't be negative years old";
        }
    }
});

person.set({name:"Jags", age:-1}
```

when I assign age - '-1', validate function is not throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Set" doesn't execute validate autoamtically. From the docs:

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true} is passed.

Call

```
person.set({name:"Jags", age:-1}, {validate: true})
```

if you want it validated.

See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate